# Unidirectional Deletion of child JPA / Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I think I have a question thousand others have already asked, but I can't find the anwnser.

I have a User with n-Authorities. Now I want to be able to delete one Authority, the result should be that the user has now (n-1) Authorities.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

// id is also there ...

@JsonIgnore
   @ManyToMany(fetch = EAGER)
   @JoinTable(name = "user_authority", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
              inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
   private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "authority")
public class Authority implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @NotNull
   @Column(columnDefinition = "char(36)")
   private String id;

   @Column(length = 50)
   private String name;
}
```

The deletion is done like this:

```
public void deleteById(final String authorityId) {
      final Optional<Authority> authorityToDelete = authorityRepository.findById(authorityId);
      authorityToDelete.ifPresent(a -> authorityRepository.delete(a));
   }
```

But I get the error about the referential integrity (Sorry the error message is in german):

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referentielle Integrität verletzt: "FKGVXJS381K6F48D5D2YI11UH89: PUBLIC.USER_AUTHORITY FOREIGN KEY(AUTHORITY_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.AUTHORITY(ID) ('bc78387e-3677-4b64-80ac-d481d0c479dc')"
```

Can anyone help? Thank you so much!

Comment: Add to annotations "@JoinColumn" properties: "insertable = false, updatable = false" in class User

Comment: Sorry @ByeBye but nothing has changed, same exception.